# The limit of $ \frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{x^2 - y^2} $ at the origin

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, multivalued-functions

I calculated it as follows, if we use the polar coordinates $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ as $r$ goes to zero, we get $ \frac{((r\cos\theta)^2+(r\sin\theta)^2)^2}{(r\cos\theta)^2 - (r\sin\theta)^2} $ , which would simplify to:

$$ \frac{((r\cos\theta)^2+(r\sin\theta)^2)^2}{(r\cos\theta)^2 - (r\sin\theta)^2} = \frac{r^4}{r^2(\cos\theta)^2 - r^2(sin\theta)^2} = \frac{r^2}{(\cos\theta)^2 - (\sin\theta)^2}$$, as $r$ goes to $0$. The limit would be zero when $(\cos\theta)^2 - (\sin\theta)^2 \neq 0$ and the limit is undefinied when $(\cos\theta)^2 - (\sin\theta)^2 = 0$, so the limit is undefined when $(\cos\theta)^2 = (\sin\theta)^2$, solving the equation we find $\theta \in \{ \pi/4 , - \pi/4, 3 \pi / 4, 5 \pi / 4 \}$.

So the limit is $0$ except when $\theta \in \{ \pi/4 , - \pi/4, 3 \pi / 4, 5 \pi / 4 \}$ the limit is undefined.

Is this solution correct?

Comment: Indeed. So the correct answer is that the limit does not exist. Note that for any small $r$ you can get closer to one of the given diagonals in the $x-y$ plane, such that $|\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta|<r^2$

Comment: There is no $\theta$ in the original problem statement, so why there is one in the answer?

Comment: @IvanNeretin What should I do then? Because I am somewhat confused

Comment: What definition of limit are you using?

Comment: The limit does not exist, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=limit+of+%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5E2%2F%28x%5E2-y%5E2%29+as+%28x%2C+y%29+approaches+%280%2C+0%29

Comment: You can't in general treat $\theta$ as a constant when you let $r \to 0$. What happens if you approach the origin along a curve such that $\theta \to \pi/4$ at the same time as $r \to 0$? This needs to be investigated. (See the comment by Andrei above.)

Comment: @CaptainChicky In general it is better not to rely on wolfram regarding two-variable limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{x^2 - y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{(x-y)(x+y)} $$
Consider the path $y=x-x^3$ and note that along this path $y\sim x$ as $x\sim 0$:
$$\frac{(x^2+y^2)}{(x-y)(x+y)}=\frac{(x^2+(x-x^3)^2)^2}{(x-x+x^3)(x+x-x^3)}\sim \frac{4x^4}{2x^4}\to 2$$
Thus the limit does not exist.